# How do I add data to a notification cloud messaging?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send extra data in a cloud message notification so I can do stuff with it when the user clicks on that notification. For example, put a doc id and the type of message it is so it sends it to the right screen in my mobile app.

My cloud function doc is written in typescript and it writes as

```
exports.listenForMessages = functions.firestore
.document("Messages/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
    data: {
      "clickAction": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "key": "message",
      "email": snapshot.data()["sender"],
    },
    notification: {
      title: snapshot.data()["nameOfSender"],
      body: snapshot.data()["message"],


    },
  };

  return messaging.sendToDevice(snapshot.data()["tokenToSendTo"], payload);
});
```

On my flutter end I have this code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
  print(event.data);


  if (event.data['type'] == 'message') {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MessageScreen(
                userName: 'Testing Now',
                email: event.data['email'] ?? '',
                profilePic: AvatarMentor(
                    email: '',
                    profilePic:
                        Image.asset(Constants.bgLoginScreenImage)))));
  }
});
```

When it returns the data comes back as {} as if there is nothing and I am puzzled why.

Comment: Do you get {} with `print(event.data)`?

Comment: Please let us know this setup is for Android or iOS platform?